# erro while using bootstrap-vue in vue3 project

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am working on `bootstrap-vue`  but I cannot add the functionalities of bootstrap. the code of main.js is

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
import"bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

and the code of Helloworld.vue file is

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>hello from helloworld</h1>
     <h5>Pressed and un-pressed state</h5>
    <b-button :pressed="true" variant="success">Always Pressed</b-button>
    <b-button :pressed="false" variant="success">Not Pressed</b-button>

    <h5 class="mt-3">Toggleable Button</h5>
    <b-button :v-bind="myToggle" variant="primary">Toggle Me</b-button>
    <p>Pressed State: <strong>{{ myToggle }}</strong></p>

    <h5>In a button group</h5>
    <b-button-group size="sm">
      <b-button
        v-for="(btn, idx) in buttons"
        :key="idx"
        :v-bind="btn.state"
        variant="primary"
      >
        {{ btn.caption }}
      </b-button>
    </b-button-group>
    <p>Pressed States: <strong>{{ btnStates }}</strong></p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
      return {
        myToggle: false,
        buttons: [
          { caption: 'Toggle 1', state: true },
          { caption: 'Toggle 2', state: false },
          { caption: 'Toggle 3', state: true },
          { caption: 'Toggle 4', state: false }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      btnStates() {
        return this.buttons.map(btn => btn.state)
      }
    }
  };

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

what I do to implement the bootstrap-vue in this project

Comment: What issue are you having? is it not being displayed correctly? any errors?

Comment: there is no error the screen is showing but the bootstrap-vue is not doing anything.

Comment: @Afaq Khan hey mate, [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) is for vue2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.js file you are missing bootstrap-vue import. Try the below for vue3, it worked for me. Please note: create a const for app.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(BootstrapVue3)
app.mount('#app')
```